# Ajax calls to TFS 15 Rest Api stopped working after upgrade

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, tfs-sdk

In TFS 2015 Update 3 everything was working without issues. I used to consume all apis using the npm package [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) without any problems. 
Using jquery the following call also would always complete correctly:

```
//this used to work in 2015 Update 3
var request = {
  url: "https://my_server/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0",
  type:'GET',
  contentType: "application/json",
  accepts: "application/json",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("my_username:my_password"));
  }
};

$.ajax(request);
```

After upgrading to TFS 15 RC2 the above mechanism is not working anymore. The server always returns a 401 - Unauthorized error.

Testing the same call via curl, everything worked out well:

```
//this works well
curl -u my_username:my_password https://my_server/tfs/DefaultCollectiopis/projects?api-version=2.0
```

But again failed when I tried to send the credentials in the header, something like this:

```
//this will fail
curl https://my_server/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0 \  
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Authorization: Basic eNjPllEmF1emEuYmFuNppOUlOnVuZGVmaW5lZA=="
```

Same 401 - Unauthorized error.

I tried to set up my Personal Access token, since it is included in TFS 15 RC2, and do a test as indicated [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics#auth)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://my_server/defaultcollection/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("" + ":" + myPatToken)
        }
    }).done(function( results ) {
        console.log( results.value[0].id + " " + results.value[0].name );
    });
});
```

and it also fails. However, after replacing myPatToken for my actual password and passing my username as well, then the request completed successfully:

```
//everything works correctly with the headers like this
headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("my_username:my_password")
        }
```

In the nutshell, something is going wrong when I setup the header like this (using jquery):

```
//this fails
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("my_username:my_password"));
  }
```

And looks like the package npm [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), which is the one I'm using, also probably uses the beforeSend property or similar and it's failing.

```
//this used to work with 2015 Update 3, not anymore after upgrading to 15 RC2
var options = {
            url: 'https://my_server/defaultcollection/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0',
            method:'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa("my_username:my_password")
            },
            json: data
      };

 request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(response);
      } else {
          console.log(error);
      }
  });
```

It makes me think it is probably something in the IIS configuration but Basic Authentication is properly configured. Is there a way to get this working using the package request?
Something changed in the IIS configuration after the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

The problems got solved after restarting the server, so I guess my case was an isolated situation, not related with TFS it self.

Now sending the request using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package seems to work well.

However, it is strange that testing it in the browser using jquery still fails. I noticed that

```
var username = "my_username",
    password = "my_password";
btoa(my_username + ":" + my_password); //generates wrong encoded string
```

generates a different encoded string then simply

```
btoa("my_username:my_password") //generates right encoded string
```

The right one is a few characters shorter, this is an example:

```
eXVuaWQuYmZGV12lpmaW5lZA==  //wrong 
eXVuaWQuYmZGVsbEAxMw==      //correct
```

No idea why, though.